# What should one use as a Sprite generator, with Rails?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, sprite

I've seen Compass' Sprite generator, which is really neat. However, if one was using Twitter Bootstrap, are there any similar solutions for a Sprite generator?

I've seen [Lemonade](https://github.com/hagenburger/lemonade) (which is now depracated and in favor of Compass) and [css_sprite](https://github.com/flyerhzm/css_sprite) which hasn't been updated for a while now. Any other options?

Comment: Looks good! But was hoping for something more on the fly / dynamic. Kinda like what Compass' Sprite generator offers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use one of the Sass port of Twitter Bootstrap, then use compass?

Here's an example I created: http://compass-bootstrap2-rails.heroku.com

```
gem "compass-rails", ">= 0.12"
gem "bootstrap-sass", ">= 2.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [Jammit](http://documentcloud.github.com/jammit/), which has a ton of other asset packaging features.